# How to solve an optimization problem with variable in indicator function?

Tags: self-study, optimization, indicator-function

How to solve the following optimization problem?

$$
\underset{D, U \in \mathbb{R}}{\min} (1+a)\text{E}_{X}[(X-D)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{D<X\leq U\}}] - (M-D)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{D<M\leq U\}},
$$
where $a, M \in \mathbb{R}$ are given; while $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is an indicator function 
$$
\mathbb{1}_{A} = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
1, \ \mbox{if } A \mbox{ holds}, \\
0, \ \mbox{otherwise}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$X$ is a random variable taking values in $\{x_1, x_2,\cdots,x_{N}\}$ with equal probability.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. 
Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.  If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. This is not homework. I find little information about indicator variables in optimization problem like this. Could you give me some advice?